# LinkedIn integration - Establish a requestToken

Tags: java, integration, linkedin-api, httpconnection

I'm developing (trying for now) portlet that will be integrated with LinkedIn.

Following the documentation about it: 
http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1008 -->
The first step to authorizing a LinkedIn member is requesting a requestToken. This request is done with an HTTP POST.
For the requestToken step, the following components should be present in your string to sign:

```
* HTTP Method (POST)
* Request URI (https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken)
* oauth_callback
* oauth_consumer_key
* oauth_nonce
* oauth_signature_method
* oauth_timestamp
* oauth_version
```

I have already API(it's *oauth_consumer_key*) key and i need to generate specific URL string.
Have next java code for this URL and HTTP connection:

```
private void processAuthentication() {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Long ms = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    Long timestamp = ms / 1000;

    Random r = new Random();
    Long nonce = r.nextLong();

    String prefixUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken";
    String oauthCallback = "oauth_callback=http://localhost/";
    String oauthConsumerKey =
            "&oauth_consumer_key=my_consumer_key";
    String oauthNonce = "&oauth_nonce=" + nonce.toString();
    String oauthSignatureMethod = "&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1";
    String oauthTimestamp = "&oauth_timestamp=" + timestamp.toString();
    String oauthVersion = "&oauth_version=1.0";

    String mainUrl =
            oauthCallback + oauthConsumerKey + oauthNonce + oauthSignatureMethod
                    + oauthTimestamp + oauthVersion;

    try {
        prefixUrl =
                URLEncoder.encode(prefixUrl, "UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode(mainUrl, "UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL(prefixUrl);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        String msg = connection.getResponseMessage();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The question is next,for those, who had faced this problem:
**How should really look URL string for connection and how response is received?**

For URL, it's interested the example of URL, you generated.
And for response interested, method to get it.
As i understand, after HTTP connection been established,that response is:

```
connection.getResponseMessage();
```

Comment: how you solved this issue ?. Any links ?

Comment: @Signare it was quite long time ago.If i remember,i will notify you.

Comment: I've found my portlet class and some related jsp's.If you need them i can post it here.As I remember,before this, you should somehow register on LinkedIn as developer to have integration access to their API

Comment: i want blackberry code, will u send me ?

Comment: I've just posted that I have,it's implemented Java for common web.I think you can adopt it for blackberry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try out the OAuth libraries to handle the connection: http://code.google.com/p/oauth/

Comment: first that i need from this repository is:
/code/java/core/consumer ?

Comment: or i should download all java related and make jar with .pom?

Answer (score 3):

@sergionni I found answer to your Question from linkedin-developer

As you know 
The first step to authorizing a Linked-In member is requesting a requestToken. This request is done with an HTTP POST.

Your base string should end up looking something like this if you're using a callback:

> POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.linkedin.com%2Fuas%2Foauth%2FrequestToken
>   &oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Foauth_callback%26o
>   auth_consumer_key%3DABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%26
>   oauth_nonce%3DoqwgSYFUD87MHmJJDv7bQqOF2EPnVus7Wkqj5duNByU%26
>   oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1259178158%26
>   oauth_version%3D1.0

You then sign this base string with your consumer_secret, computing a signature. In this case, if your secret was 1234567890, the signature would be TLQXuUzM7omwDbtXimn6bLDvfF8=.

Now you take the signature you generated, along with oauth_nonce, oauth_callback, oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp, oauth_consumer_key, and oauth_version and create an HTTP Authorization header. For this request, that HTTP header would look like:

> Authorization: OAuth
>   oauth_nonce="oqwgSYFUD87MHmJJDv7bQqOF2EPnVus7Wkqj5duNByU",
>   oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth_callback",
>   oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
>   oauth_timestamp="1259178158",
>   oauth_consumer_key="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
>   oauth_signature="TLQXuUzM7omwDbtXimn6bLDvfF8=",
>   oauth_version="1.0"

Please note, that the HTTP header is a single header -- not an HTTP header for each component. You can optionally supply a realm="http://api.linkedin.com".

As a response to your request for a requestToken, your requestToken will be in the "oauth_token" response field, a validation that we acknowledged your callback with the "oauth_callback_confirmed" field, an oauth_token_secret, and a oauth_expires_in, and a few other values.

(here us Your answaer) response would look like:

> oauth_token=94ab03c4-ae2c-45e4-8732-0e6c4899db63
>   &oauth_token_secret=be6ccb24-bf0a-4ea8-a4b1-0a70508e452b
>   &oauth_callback_confirmed=true&oauth_expires_in=599

Comment: if you have Sample Java code(with description like above) for next step like
* Redirect the User to Linkedin Authorization Server
* Request the access token
* How to make 1st API request to getting Users info then drop me email on mcs5vaibhav@rediff.com 

Hope for Best co-operation from your side

Answer (score 0):

I created a plugin for Play Framework to easily integrated with LinkedIn's OAuth: geeks.aretotally.in/projects/play-framework-linkedin-module. Hopefully it can help. You should def check out Play, very very cool Java framework.

Answer (score 0):

portlet body:

```
public class LinkedInPortlet extends GenericPortlet {

    public static final String PAGE_PIN = "pin";

    public static final String PAGE_EDIT = "edit";

    public static final String PAGE_PROFILE = "profile";

    public static final String PAGE_CONNECTIONS = "connections";

    public static final String FORM_LINKEDIN_PREFERENCES = "preferencesLinkedInForm";

    public static final String PAGE_VIEW_MY_PROFILE = "/WEB-INF/portlets/linkedin/myProfile.jsp";

    public static final String PAGE_VIEW_MY_CONNECTIONS =
            "/WEB-INF/portlets/linkedin/myConnections.jsp";

    public static final String PAGE_PREFERENCES = "/WEB-INF/portlets/linkedin/edit.jsp";

    public void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) throws PortletException,
        IOException {

        String view = PAGE_VIEW_MY_PROFILE;

        String page =
                (String) request.getPortletSession().getAttribute(
                        "page_" + getPortletIdentifier(request), PortletSession.PORTLET_SCOPE);

        String accessTokenToken =
                getStringConfiguration(request, LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_ACCESS_TOKEN_TOKEN);
        String accessTokenSecret =
                getStringConfiguration(request, LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

        LinkedInContact profile = new LinkedInContact();
        List<LinkedInContact> contacts = new ArrayList<LinkedInContact>();

        if (PAGE_PIN.equals(page)) {
            view = PAGE_PREFERENCES;
        } else if (PAGE_EDIT.equals(page)) {
            view = PAGE_PREFERENCES;
        } else if (PAGE_CONNECTIONS.equals(page)) {
            try {
                contacts =
                        ServiceResolver.getResolver().getLinkedInService().getConnections(
                                accessTokenToken, accessTokenSecret);
            } catch (ServiceException se) {
                view = PAGE_PREFERENCES;
                handleException(request, se);
            }
            view = PAGE_VIEW_MY_CONNECTIONS;
        } else {
            try {
                profile =
                        ServiceResolver.getResolver().getLinkedInService().getProfile(
                                accessTokenToken, accessTokenSecret);
            } catch (ServiceException se) {
                view = PAGE_PREFERENCES;
                handleException(request, se);
            }

            view = PAGE_VIEW_MY_PROFILE;
        }

        request.setAttribute("profile", profile);
        request.setAttribute("contacts", contacts);

        response.setContentType(request.getResponseContentType());
        PortletRequestDispatcher rd = getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher(view);
        rd.include(request, response);

    }

    public void processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
        throws PortletException, IOException {

        String action;

        action = (String) request.getParameter("action");

        String page = request.getParameter("page");

        if (page == null) {
            page = PAGE_PROFILE;
        } else if ("auth".equals(action)) {
            request.getPortletSession().setAttribute(
                    "requestToken_" + getPortletIdentifier(request),
                    ServiceResolver.getResolver().getLinkedInService().getRequestToken(),
                    PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
            LinkedInPreferencesForm form = new LinkedInPreferencesForm(request);
            request.getPortletSession().setAttribute(
                    FORM_LINKEDIN_PREFERENCES + getPortletIdentifier(request), form,
                    PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
            response.setPortletMode(PortletMode.EDIT);
        } else if ("save".equals(action)) {
            try {
                try {
                    savePreferences(request, response);
                } catch (ServiceException e) {
                    handleException(request, e);
                }
            } catch (PortletModeException e) {
                handleException(request, e);
            }
        } else if ("myProfile".equals(action)) {
            page = PAGE_PROFILE;
        } else if ("myConnections".equals(action)) {
            page = PAGE_CONNECTIONS;
        }

        if (page != null) {
            request.getPortletSession().setAttribute("page_" + getPortletIdentifier(request), page,
                    PortletSession.PORTLET_SCOPE);
        }
    }

    private void savePreferences(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
        throws PortletModeException, ServiceException {

        LinkedInPreferencesForm form = new LinkedInPreferencesForm(request);

        if (validateForm(request, form)) {

            LinkedInRequestToken requestToken =
                    (LinkedInRequestToken) request.getPortletSession().getAttribute(
                            "requestToken_" + getPortletIdentifier(request),
                            PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);

            String pin = request.getParameter("pinCode");

            LinkedInAccessToken accessToken;

            try {
                accessToken =
                        ServiceResolver.getResolver().getLinkedInService().getAccessToken(
                                requestToken, pin);
            } catch (LinkedInOAuthServiceException ase) {
                response.setPortletMode(PortletMode.EDIT);
                throw new ServiceException("linkedin.authentication.failed");

            }

            String tokenToken = requestToken.getToken();
            String secret = requestToken.getTokenSecret();
            String tokenURL = requestToken.getAuthorizationUrl();

            Properties configuration = new Properties();
            configuration.setProperty(LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_PIN, form.getPin());
            configuration
                    .setProperty(LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_REQUEST_TOKEN_TOKEN, tokenToken);
            configuration.setProperty(LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_REQUEST_TOKEN_SECRET, secret);
            configuration.setProperty(LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, tokenURL);
            configuration.setProperty(LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_ACCESS_TOKEN_TOKEN, accessToken
                    .getToken());

            configuration.setProperty(LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
                    accessToken.getTokenSecret());
            ServiceResolver.getResolver().getPortalService().savePortletConfiguration(request,
                    configuration);

            resetSessionForm(request, FORM_LINKEDIN_PREFERENCES);
            response.setPortletMode(PortletMode.VIEW);

        } else {
            // store in session
            request.getPortletSession().setAttribute(
                    FORM_LINKEDIN_PREFERENCES + getPortletIdentifier(request), form,
                    PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
            response.setPortletMode(PortletMode.EDIT);
            logger.debug(FORM_LINKEDIN_PREFERENCES + " is in edit mode");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void addConfiguration(MessageSource messageSource, Locale locale,
        Map<String, String> result) {
        result.put(LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_PIN, messageSource.getMessage(
                "linkedIn.preferences.pin", null, locale));
        result.put(LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_REQUEST_TOKEN_TOKEN, messageSource.getMessage(
                "linkedIn.preferences.requestTokenToken", null, locale));
        result.put(LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_REQUEST_TOKEN_SECRET, messageSource.getMessage(
                "linkedIn.preferences.requestTokenSecret", null, locale));
        result.put(LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, messageSource.getMessage(
                "linkedIn.preferences.requestTokenURL", null, locale));
        result.put(LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_ACCESS_TOKEN_TOKEN, messageSource.getMessage(
                "linkedIn.preferences.accessToken", null, locale));
        result.put(LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, messageSource.getMessage(
                "linkedIn.preferences.accessTokenSecret", null, locale));
    }

    @Override
    protected void addPreference(MessageSource messageSource, Locale locale,
        Map<String, String> result) {
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsyncTitle(RenderRequest request) {
        return this.getTitle(request);
    }

    protected boolean validateForm(ActionRequest request, LinkedInPreferencesForm form) {
        return form.validate();
    }

    protected String myEdit(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response)
        throws PortletException, IOException {

        LinkedInPreferencesForm form = new LinkedInPreferencesForm();

        form.setPin(getStringConfiguration(request, LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_PIN));
        form.setRequestTokenToken(getStringConfiguration(request,
                LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_REQUEST_TOKEN_TOKEN));
        form.setRequestTokenSecret(getStringConfiguration(request,
                LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_REQUEST_TOKEN_SECRET));
        form.setRequestTokenURL(getStringConfiguration(request,
                LinkedInPreferencesForm.PARAM_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL));

        registerSessionForm(request, FORM_LINKEDIN_PREFERENCES, form);

        LinkedInRequestToken requestToken;

        requestToken =
                (LinkedInRequestToken) request.getPortletSession().getAttribute(
                        "requestToken_" + getPortletIdentifier(request),
                        PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);

        if (requestToken == null) {
            requestToken =
                    new LinkedInRequestToken(form.getRequestTokenToken(), form
                            .getRequestTokenSecret());
            requestToken.setAuthorizationUrl(form.getRequestTokenURL());
        }

        request.setAttribute("requestToken", requestToken);

        return PAGE_PREFERENCES;

    }
}
```